# FORM HTML5 e PHP tudo na mesma pagina

Tags: php, mysql, html5

**Como processar essas tarefas antes do formulário ser gravado no banco de dados?**

**CASO 01:**
Como impedir que o ***mandante*** não seja repetido no ***visitante***?

**CASO 02:**
Como determinar vencedor ou empate?

**CASO 03:**
Determinado o **CASO 02**, como gravá-lo no campo oculto ***tipo***?

**CASO 04:**
Havendo vencedor, como gravá-lo no campo oculto ***resultado***?

**CASO 05:**
Como exibir a mensagem de ***FORM gravado com sucesso***, somente se todas as requisições forem atendidas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
include("bd.php"); //Conectando com o MySQL
?>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Registro de resultado dos jogos</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="estilos.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="site"> 
        <form method="post" id="insere_jgfeito" align="center" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <!-- ÍNICIO DO USUÁRIO PREENCHENDO FORMULÁRIO -->

            <td>
            <tr>
                <span><strong>Inserir Resultados<strong></span>
            </br>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>
<select required name="campeonato"/>
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Campeonato</option>
    <?php
        $cst_campeonato = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `campeonato` FROM `tbl_campeonatos` WHERE `status` = 1 ORDER BY `id` ASC");
            while($campeonatos = mysql_fetch_array($cst_campeonato)){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $campeonatos["id"];?>"><tr><?php echo $campeonatos["campeonato"];?></tr></option>
    <?php } ?>
<select>            </td></br>
            <td>
            <label for="data-atual">Realizado em...</label>
            <input type="date" name="data-atual" id="data-atual" value="<?=date('d/m/Y')?>" required>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </td></br>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <select required name="mandante"/>
                <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Mandante</option>
                <?php
                    $cst_competidor = mysql_query("SELECT `tbl_jogadores`.`tecnico` AS tecnico, `tbl_competidor`.`nome` AS nome FROM `tbl_competidor` INNER JOIN `tbl_jogadores` ON `tbl_competidor`.`id_competidor` = `tbl_jogadores`.`tecnico` WHERE `tbl_competidor`.`status` = 1 GROUP BY `tbl_jogadores`.`tecnico` ORDER BY `tbl_competidor`.`nome` ASC");
                    while($tecnicos = mysql_fetch_array($cst_competidor)){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $tecnicos["tecnico"];?>"><tr><?php echo $tecnicos["nome"];?></tr></option>
                <?php } ?>
            <select>
            <input type="number" min="0" max="9" name="mscore" required="required">
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="number" min="0" max="9" name="vscore" required="required">
            <select required name="visitante"/>
                <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Visitante</option>
                <?php
                    $cst_competidor = mysql_query("SELECT `tbl_jogadores`.`tecnico` AS tecnico, `tbl_competidor`.`nome` AS nome FROM `tbl_competidor` INNER JOIN `tbl_jogadores` ON `tbl_competidor`.`id_competidor` = `tbl_jogadores`.`tecnico` WHERE `tbl_competidor`.`status` = 1 GROUP BY `tbl_jogadores`.`tecnico` ORDER BY `tbl_competidor`.`nome` ASC");
                    while($tecnicos = mysql_fetch_array($cst_competidor)){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $tecnicos["tecnico"];?>"><tr><?php echo $tecnicos["nome"];?></tr></option>
                <?php } ?>
            <select>
            </td>
            </tr>   
            <input type="hidden" value="?" name="tipo"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="?" name="resultado"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="status"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="enviado" />
            <button type="submit">Gravar</button>
        </form> <!-- FIM DO FORMULÁRIO -->
    </div>
<?php 
/* RECEBENDO OS DADOS PREENCHIDOS DO FORMULÁRIO!
OBS: Para fins didáticos, todas as variavés utilizarão o prefixo "rcb_" referente a "recebe valor de" */

$rcb_campeonato = $_POST ["campeonato"];    // Captura o (select) com nome: "campeonato" referente ao "id_campeonato"
$rcb_data_atual = $_POST ["data-atual"];    // Traz (input date) com nome: "data-atual" 
$rcb_mandante   = $_POST ["mandante"];      // Captura o participante de nome: "mandante"
$rcb_mscore = $_POST ["mscore"];            // Recebe número entre 0 e 9 de: "mscore"
$rcb_vscore = $_POST ["vscore"];            // Recebe número entre 0 e 9 de: "vscore"
$rcb_visitante  = $_POST ["visitante"];     // Captura o participante de nome: "mandante"
$rcb_tipo   = $_POST ["tipo"];              // Campo oculto de valores 0=Empate, 1=Vitória do mandante ou 2=Visitante
$rcb_resultado = $_POST ["resultado"];      // Deve gravar o ID vencedor (mandante ou visitante) 
$rcb_status = $_POST ["status"];            // Se tudo estiver OK, grava sempre o campo com valor 1.


//Como gravar esses dados no banco de dados?


//Como referenciar a tabela do banco de dados?


$query = "INSERT INTO `tbl_jogos` ( `Null` , `id_campeonato`, `dt_partida` , `mandante` , `visitante` , `mscore` , `vscore` , `tipo` , `resultado`, `status`) 
VALUES ('$rcb_campeonato', '$rcb_data_atual', '$rcb_mandante', '$rcb_visitante', '$rcb_mscore', '$rcb_vscore', '$rcb_tipo', '$rcb_resultado', '$rcb_status')";

echo "Seu resultado foi gravado com sucesso!";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Utilize estruturas condicionais..

Comment: Tente separar, html, do php, e no php crie as classes de persistência

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CASO 01**: basta criar uma condicional e disparar algum erro se passar...

```
if($rcb_visitante == $rcb_mandante) {
    echo "O mandante não pode ser igual ao visitante.";
}
```

**CASO 02**: basta adicionar duas variáveis: `$vencedor` (*string*) e `$empate` (*boolean*) e populá-las a partir de mais uma condicional. Ps.: para os casos seguintes, criei mais variáveis para auxiliar na impressão: `$tipo` e `$resultado`.

```
$vencedor = $empate = false;
$tipo = $resultado = "?";
if($rcb_mscore == $rcb_vscore) {
   $empate = true;
   $tipo = "0";
} elseif($rcb_mscore > $rcb_vscore) {
   $vencedor = $resultado = $rcb_mandante;
   $tipo = "1";
} else {
   $vencedor = $resultado = $rcb_visitante;
   $tipo = "2";
}
```

**CASO 03**: para poder realizar essa operação, esse processo de validação deve vir **ANTES** da exibição do formulário, de modo em que, no trecho onde escrevemos o campo `tipo` possamos populá-lo dinamicamente, por exemplo:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$tipo?>" name="tipo"/>
```

**CASO 04**: da mesma forma que a etapa anterior...

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$resultado?>" name="resultado"/>
```

CASO 05: ao final de todos os processos, será necessário ter uma variável que indique que o formulário passou pelo processo de validação. Neste caso, vou aproveitar para colocar o código todo de como ficaria esse processo.
Obs.: me baseei unicamente na estrutura que você estava seguindo nesse exercício, mas essa estrutura e forma de trabalho não é uma boa prática. O ideal é separar o que é server-side do que é client-side, isto é, sua resposta de formulário poderia ser uma requisição AJAX. Porém, pelo nível da coisa acredito que ainda não seja hora de falar sobre isso, hehe. Recomendo o aprendizado: Javascript > AJAX > jQuery > jQuery.AJAX + PHP. Vai mudar um pouco sua visão sobre o assunto. Enfim, vamos o código:

https://pastebin.com/hXr0nGGi

*De todo modo, todavia, porém, toda a estrutura do seu HTML está cheia de erros... Tenha um pouco mais de paciência nos estudos, creio que esteja indo rápido demais... Só um conselho.* Como falei, segui o que você estava tentando fazer (com validações server-side), mas essas validações só vão ocorrer quando o usuário enviar o formulário (a página será recarregada). Se a sua intenção é prevenir isso, sua validação terá de ser client-side (Javascript). Eu posso elaborar uma resposta fazendo as mesmas coisas com jQuery (pra explicar mais rápido, porque haja tempo... haha).